# JavaScript ADAL renew token on non-route change?

Tags: angularjs, adal, adal.js

We've gone ahead and gone through http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/10/28/adal-javascript-and-angularjs-deep-dive/ and set up Azure on our SPA that uses AngularJS as the frontend and WebAPI as the backend.

We authenticate perfectly and everything runs smoothly.  However, after an hour the token expires as expected and doesn't refresh until a route change.  That means that users in our system sitting on a page and then making a GET to the server will have their authentication fail, causing them to lose the data on the screen as we call _adal.login() to get the token going again.

My question is: how do we renew the token either automatically when our index wrapper detects the token is going to expire soon or alternatively, how do we set up ADAL to open the iFrame and renew the token on HTTP requests?

Everything I seem to find only suggests that we let the route change handle re-authentication but unfortunately that's causing issues for our users.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to change route in order to get a renewed token. Whenever the interceptor senses a call toward the backend (or one of the registered endpoints) it attempts to retrieve the appropriate token form the cache, and if the token is within 5 mins from expiration (or not present) then ADAL automatically uses the hidden iframe  to renew it. You should not need to call login explicitly. Also, the session cookie with Azure AD is the artifact required to perform the silent token renewal - and that lasts more than 1 hour. I am wondering what is going wrong. If you contact me at http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/contact/ with more details I am happy to look into this further.

Comment: I've left you a message on your site with information regarding the project I'm working on.  There's a good chance I've inherited a project using a version of Angular that is old enough that some functionality within your adal-angular.js library may be too modern for, but I'm not well-versed on it yet to truly determine if that's the case.

Thanks again!

Comment: Adal.js doesn't referesh the token. Do I need to implement angular-adal to refresh token works?

Comment: ADAL.js does renew tokens. What methods are you calling?